# Density of a subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ be open, bounded and simply connected with smooth boundary $\partial\Omega$. Define $\mathcal{H}:=\{u\in H^1(\Omega)~|~\Delta u\in L^2(\Omega)\}$ with norm
$$\|u\|_\mathcal{H}^2:=\|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)}^2+\|\Delta u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2.$$
I want to show that $H^2(\Omega)$ is dense in $\mathcal{H}$ under $\|\cdot\|_\mathcal{H}$.

This means, given $u\in\mathcal{H}$ and $\varepsilon>0$ I need to find a $u_0\in H^2(\Omega)$ such that
$$\|u-u_0\|_{H^1(\Omega)}^2+\|\Delta u-\Delta u_0\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2<\varepsilon.$$

Alternatively it means that given a sequence $u_n\in{H}^2(\Omega)$ that is Cauchy in $\|\cdot\|_\mathcal{H}$ I need to show that its limit $u$ is in $\mathcal{H}$.

So far I've attempted reasoning as follows:

If $u_n$ is $\mathcal{H}$-Cauchy then also it is $H^1(\Omega)$-Cauchy, i.e.,
$$\|u_n-u_m\|_{H^1(\Omega)}\rightarrow0\qquad(n,m\rightarrow\infty).$$
Hence by completeness there is an $H^1(\Omega)$-limit $u$:
$$\|u_n-u\|_{H^1(\Omega)}\rightarrow0\qquad(n\rightarrow\infty).$$
The issue here is that $\Delta u$ is not necessarily defined. One may of course remark that by the same reasoning in the complete space $L^2(\Omega)$ the sequence $\Delta u_n$ has a limit, say, $y$, in $L^2(\Omega)$. But there is no immediate link between $y$ and $u$.

Could one attempt to solve the Dirichlet problem
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rclcc}
\Delta f &=&y&\text{in}&\Omega\\
f&=&u|_{\partial\Omega}&\text{on}&\partial\Omega
\end{array}\right.\quad?$$
This seems like an incredibly convoluted way to do it, when I feel it should be extremely simple---$H^2(\Omega)$ is trivially $H^1$-dense in $H^1(\Omega)$.

Comment: Isn't $C^\infty(\Omega)$ dense in $\mathcal H$? If that is the case then you're done, since $C^\infty\subset H^2(\Omega)$.

Comment: $C^\infty(\Omega)$ is dense in $H^1(\Omega)$ under the $H^1$-norm. I believe it is dense in $\mathcal{H}$ under the $\mathcal{H}$-norm, but that Laplacian keeps getting in the way of proving it; there's no obvious way to control $\|\Delta f\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$, even if $f$ is smooth.

Comment: Hum. If $\Omega=\mathbb R^n$, then $\mathcal{H}$ is exactly equal to $H^2(\mathbb R^n)$. The same if we consider functions that vanish on $\partial \Omega$ with their first derivatives (i.e., $H^2_0(\Omega)$). In the general case, there's a boundary term: $$\lVert \Delta f\rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}^2=\lVert D^2 f\rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 + \sum_{ij}\int_{\partial \Omega}(\partial_j f \partial_i^2 f n_j - \partial_j f \partial_i\partial_q f n_q)\, dS.$$You probably know these things already but that's all I can say